# C++ unordered-map good number of buckets

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map

I know on construction of an unordered map `M` that I will insert exactly `k` elements. How should I choose n the number of Buckets for `M`?

I am considering to use `n = 10*k` to get a reasonable trade-off between size and collision chance.

Comment: Just let the implementation of `std::unordered_map` decide that for you unless you can *prove* (by *meassuring*)  that this is too far from optimal for your usecase.

Comment: Well, `std::unordered_map` does not know how many elements I will insert. I think it would be desirable to take advantage of that knowledge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of `k == n` is not a bad choice.  The default `max_load_factor` for the unordered containers is 1.0.  This means that the container won't reallocate more buckets until `k > n`.  If you desire another `max_load_factor`, then construct your container, set the `max_load_factor`, and then call `reserve(k)`, and that will allocate enough buckets for `k` elements with your current `max_load_factor`.

The selection of a good max_load_factor depends on the type of hashing data structure being used.  [Here is a good description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) of two major types:  chaining and open addressing.  This description contains a [nice chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#mediaviewer/File:Hash_table_average_insertion_time.png) which shows the average number of collisions vs load factor for these two basic hash data structure designs.

The std::unordered containers are constrained to use the chaining design, and so you can get a feel for the collisions you can expect with a load factor of 1.

The committee is motivated to have its containers work for most situations out of the box, with no need for a lot of tweaking.  The committee felt a default `max_load_factor` of 1 would be a decent compromise between memory use and performance degradation due to collisions.

If you aren't sure, let the containers default.  And if you are curious, change the defaults and measure (speed and memory usage).

Comment: Well this leads to the Question, what is a good `max_load_factor`. Do you think that 1.0 would be desirable? In theory a `max_load_factor` of 1.0 means almost certain hash collusion, right?